# where to transform data in React app - in express or on front end with React?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, express

I have an application for creating leagues. My JSON data is structured as below.
I want to create a league table based on the fixture data.
Should i loop through the fixtures and calculate each players league data on the front-end (im using react) or do it on the backend (express)?
Or is there a better alternative?

Thanks

```html
const leagueData = [
  {
    "league_id":1,
    "players": [
      {"player_id": 1, "name": "Paul Langley", "nickname": "Langers"},
      {"player_id": 2, "name": "Anthony Gayton", "nickname": "Drax"}, 
      {"player_id": 3, "name": "Mark Stiles", "nickname": "Raynaud"},
      {"player_id": 4, "name": "Chris Corse", "nickname": "Eggbum"},
      {"player_id": 5, "name": "Elna", "nickname": "Elna"},
      {"player_id": 6, "name": "Craig Mant", "nickname": "Craigenhead"},
      {"player_id": 7, "name": "Karl", "nickname": "Karl"},
      {"player_id": 8, "name": "Chris Farrell", "nickname": "Fazza"},
      {"player_id": 9, "name": "Paul Lynch", "nickname": "Paul"},
      {"player_id": 10, "name": "Neil", "nickname": "Neil"},    
      {"player_id": 11, "name": "Dug Buchanen", "nickname": "Dug"}, 
      {"player_id": 12, "name": "Justin", "nickname": "Justin"},    
      {"player_id": 13, "name": "Polish Builder", "nickname": "Pole"}    
    ],
    "fixtures": [
      {
        "fixture_id":1,
        "date": "17/05/2017",
        "played":true,
        "teams": {
          "team1": [1 ,2, 3, 4, 5],
          "team2": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        },
        "score1":10,
        "score2":0
      },
      {
        "fixture_id":2,
        "date": "24/05/2017",
        "played":false,
        "teams": {
          "team1": [1 ,2, 3, 4, 5],
          "team2": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        },
        "score1":0,
        "score2":0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would do this on the backend.

- Easier to test
- Less load on client side (Quicker time to first paint)
- Allows you to re-structure/refactor your data at any time

Answer (score 0):

yes you should use the .map (array) function to plot the view in front end